# Explanation request for verses 10, 11, 12, and 13 from the Manasa Khanda of the Skanda Purana?

Tags: skanda-purana

Need an explanation of verses 10, 11, 12, and 13 from the Manasa Khanda of the Skanda Purana

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! It would be nice if you could provide a link or reproduce the verses together with the chapter number